# Converting images to greyscale using intervention

Tags: php, laravel-5, grayscale, intervention

I am trying to convert my images into greyscale and then downloading it in **Laravel** but each and every time I am getting this error

> The file "" does not exist

Dont' know why it giving this error here is my code.

```
$file = public_path() . "/large/s/" . $sheet[0]->sheet_f_id . '-s.jpg';
$image = Image::make($file);
$grayScale = $image->greyscale();
return Response::download($grayScale);
```

When I dump my `$file` variable I got the response something like this.

> "D:\xampp\htdocs\wikistaging\public/large/s/03-02-05-025-s.jpg"

But still it is giving me the sam error why is that happening. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download then first you have to save the created file and need to give the path to download. Here is working example

```
$img_name=$sheet[0]->sheet_f_id . '-s.jpg';
$destination_path=public_path() . "/large/s/";

$file = $destination_path.$img_name;
$image = Image::make($file);

$image->greyscale()->save($destination_path.'gray-'.$img_name);
return Response::download($destination_path.'gray_'.$img_name);
```

And if you don't want to keep the file you can delete, replace the last line with below line.

```
return Response::download($destination_path.'gray_'.$img_name)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: sir it didn't work for me as it gives me this error. `The file "D:\xampp\htdocs\wikistaging\public/large/s/gray_03-02-05-029-s.jpg" does not exist` now

Comment: @MohsinAbbas Code is checked and working on my end, please check the path you are using correct or not.

Comment: Sir you are right code is working on your side but now it is giving me this error now. `Image source not readable`

Comment: Please sir can you tell me what is it that is wrong also grey folder is not making but file is saving in large/s with the name grey-filename

Comment: Grey folder will not create we are adding grey only for distinguishing, try to print this $file is it getting full path or not.

Comment: Thank you so much sir it now worked for me +1 for that little extra hint about that path thing.

Comment: @MohsinAbbas Great, if it will help you accept and up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must save your image after call **greyscale()**.
You can try it:

```
$filePath = public_path() . "/large/s/" . $sheet[0]->sheet_f_id . '-s-test.jpg';
$image->greyscale();
$image->save($filePath);
```